# How to perform a PDF conversion in Event Receiver?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to convert the document a `.docx` file available in document library(conversion) to PDF format in same library whenever the file is updated.

The code I am using is given below:

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
           {          
                   ConversionJob job = new ConversionJob(wordAutomationServiceName);
                   job.UserToken = properties.Web.CurrentUser.UserToken;
                   job.Settings.UpdateFields = true;
                   job.Settings.OutputFormat = SaveFormat.PDF;
                   string input = siteURL + "Conversion/Test.docx";
                   string output = siteURL + "Conversion/Test.pdf";
                   job.AddFile(input, output);
                   job.Start();
           }
```

When I run it in debug mode, it executes without any error or exception but it is not generating any PDF file.

I am not able to find out what the problem is

it tried this simple code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.Conversions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string siteUrl = "http://siteurl";
        string wordAutomationServiceName = "Word Automation Services";
        using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(siteUrl))
        {
            ConversionJob job = new ConversionJob(wordAutomationServiceName);
            job.UserToken = spSite.UserToken;
            job.Settings.UpdateFields = true;
            job.Settings.OutputFormat = SaveFormat.PDF;
            job.AddFile(siteUrl + "/Shared%20Documents/Test.docx",
            siteUrl + "/Shared%20Documents/Test.pdf");
            job.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

This also did nt workd
what i feel is there is no error in code must be some problem with sharepoint settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a Document object?

I'm not sure if you can use this in your context, but if yes, you could try:

```
docObject.ExportAsFixedFormat("Yourdoc.pdf", WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, false,
                        WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint, WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 0, 0,
                        WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, true, true,
                        WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, true, false, false, ref oMissing);
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb256835%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: note that this code is using the Office Word API, which means you will need to install Office on your server(s).

Answer (score -1):

I assume you took your code from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742315.aspx). Where did you wordAutomationServiceName? Because it needs to match the name of the Word Automation Service you configured in the Central Administration.

Also check the SharePoint TraceLog (14/LOGS) or the EventViewer for further information/errors. Also see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557330.aspx) article about how to configure Word Automation Services for Development.

[How Word Automation Services Work](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2010/01/18/word-automation-services-_2d00_-how-it-works.aspx)

Comment: Hi 
thanks for replying

Word Autimation  service is already configured.

I have admin rights on the site and also checked the server logs.

but i dont have microsoft office installed on the server.

Is this necessary to have ms office installed?

Comment: no it's not necessary. heres a good article about how the word automation services work http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2010/01/18/word-automation-services-_2d00_-how-it-works.aspx

Comment: What i understood from this link is that , the start returns just after placing the conversion request in the DB. As my code is wrkng fine so i feel, request is being placed successfully in DB but  is not picked by by the service later.  what can i do for it??